# expand each row to multiple rows in pandas using dataframe.apply (similar to MapReduce)

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a simplified version of my problem.
I have a DataFrame that has start and end locations of trips.
I want to end up with a DataFrame that has for each station
the number of arrivals and departures.

I am familiar with MapReduce-like workflows, where in the
Map phase I can take in one row and output multiple rows,
and then aggregate over all rows in the reduce phase.

Here's the code that I have now, that DOES NOT work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def expand_row(row):
  return pd.Series(
    { 'station': [row['start_station'], row['end_station']],
      'departures': [1, 0],
      'arrivals': [0, 1],
    },
  )

trips = pd.DataFrame({
  'start_station': ['a', 'c'],
  'end_station': ['b', 'a'],
})

expanded = df.apply(expand_row, axis=1)
aggregated = expanded.groupby('station').aggregate(np.sum)
```

What I want as my final DataFrame is

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'station': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'departures': [1, 0, 1],
  'arrivals': [1, 1, 0]
})
desired_df.index = desired_df.pop('station')
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
trips = pd.DataFrame({
  'start_station': ['a', 'c'],
  'end_station': ['b', 'a'],
})
trips.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

the result is:

```
   end_station  start_station
a            1              1
b            1              0
c            0              1
```

Comment: Accepted your answer since it does indeed work for my simplified example. Many thanks.
For my use case however, I also had a timestamp on each trip, and I wanted to preserve that, so I ended up doing: 
* Split trips into departures and arrivals.
* Each also has a 'time'
* num_departures_per_station = departures.groupby('time').size()
* num_arrivals_per_station = arrivals.groupby('time').size()